# SetMethod() doesn't work properly

Tags: r, r-s4

I have defined a class (S4) and called it `LD`. For this class I specified a method, which I gave a name`subject`.

```
setClass("LD",
     slots = list(id = "numeric", 
                  age = "numeric",
                  gender = "character"))

setGeneric("subject", function(x){
  standardGeneric("subject")
})

setMethod("subject",
              signature(x = "LD", n ="numeric"),
              function(x, n){
               if(sum(x@id != n)==0){
                 return(NULL)
               } else {
                 return(paste0("Subject ID: ", n))
               }
              })
```

I am getting the following Error Message:

```
Error in match.call(definition, call, expand.dots, envir) : 
  unused argument (n = c("numeric", ""))
```

Comment: According to TFM, `standardGeneric` takes 2 arguments (a name and a function). And it says the calls to this standardGeneric are not usually executed by the programmer. And I would have imagined that if you did need to do so, you would have made the second argument a function that takes two arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, setting `setGeneric("subject", function(x, ...) {standardGeneric("subject")
})` helped to overcome the problem!

Comment: This error is triggered because the argument `n` is not an argument of the generic function `subject`. All arguments must be arguments of the generic (the easiest way to achieve this being, as you have found out, to add `...` to the generic's definition)